# What is the client install footprint for Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Just read some posts about how wonderful Silverlight 3.0 is, including that it uses some variant of WPF. That set off a warning flag.

If I'm installing Silverlight on the client and I've got, say Win XP SP2 (which is the minimum supported), how large would the runtime download be, including all dependencies?

(In the past I've had a MS .net product manager tell me a .net 2.0 app was just an xcopy. He forgot to mention that this was assuming that you'd already installed the 22 MB runtime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total download size 4.69MB for Windows, [8.7MB for Mac](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/development_tools/silverlight.html). No other dependencies. I believe they may expand once they're downloaded.

Note that the developer runtimes are (of course) larger.